# Positioning of imported table

Tags: tables, positioning

I am importing a data table into a document and want the table to be within the text. When I import with `\input{bodyrate}[htpb]`, the table is placed at the end of the document and `[htpb]` is printed instead. How do I get the table to be where I import it in the .tex file?

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}
\begin{document}
\input{file}[htpb]
\end{document}
```

the table file begins with:

```
\begin{deluxetable}{lccc}
\tablecolumns{4}
\tablewidth{0pc}
```

I tried creating a table environment, but am getting the error: "! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode."

```
\begin{table}
    \import{file)
\end{table}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be identical to your earlier question, and as you were told then, you can not use `[htbp]` with `\input`. deluxetable is a non standard floating environment if you do not want a float why are you using that (not very common) construct?

Comment: What construct do you suggest?

Comment: This isn't the place to discus that, you should delete the question as it is a duplicate, rather than wait for people to vote to close it, you can edit and clarify your initial question.

Comment: I clarified my initial question, but no one provided a solution.  What else was I supposed to do once people stopped responding?

Comment: Your initial question isn't even close to being clear, questions are supposed to have a complete document that people can run locally that _demonstrates_ the problem. If you edit a question to clarify it then it will come back to the top of the active page and people will see it. Duplicate questions (from different people) are closed if possible, duplicate  questions from the same person are basically considered spam.